# Declare Flow Types For Props Added By 3rd Party Component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am using Victory JS to create charts in React. Victory has a component called `<VictoryBar>` which can take a prop called `labelComponent` which I am passing `<BarLabel/>`.

Example:

```jsx
<VictoryBar
  labelComponent={<BarLabel/>}
/>
```

The problem is I am using Flow for type checking and `VictoryBar` adds props to `<BarLabel/>`. Here is my type for BarLabel props and the component itself. I explain the problem in the comment.

```jsx
type BarLabelProps = {
  style?: Object,
  x?: number,
  y0?: number,

  // The problem lies here. When datum is optional I get the flow error
  // that props.datum.name is invalid because .name cannot be accessed from a 
  // possibly null value. When it is required (no question mark) I get an error 
  // because when I pass the component to <VictoryBar /> it does not contain
  // the prop datum until VictoryBar does it's thing. 
  datum?: Object,
};

function BarLabel(props: BarLabelProps) {
  return (
    <text
      textAnchor="middle"
      style={props.style}
      x={props.x + 70}
      y={props.y0 + 15}
    >
      <tspan style={props.style}>
        {props.datum.name}
      </tspan>
    </text>
  );
}
```

The flow docs give an example of specifying props on a Higher Order function, but doesn't help me with the scenario. **How can I tell flow that these props are added via `VictoryBar` ?**

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I'm not very experienced with React and Flow's special-cases for it, but I don't think there is currently a way to model this.

Comment: @Pizza-r0b, can you want to throw up an repro-repo/codesandbox for this? I'd like to help, but I'm a little lazy and don't want to setup the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

To support Flow types for third-party libraries in your project, you can use the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed) module. Their installation instructions say to install globally, e.g. `yarn global add flow-typed` or `npm install -g flow-typed`.

As of now, Victory [doesn't have any official Flow types defined](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm) so once you've installed this module, you will need to create a stub to remove your Flow errors for the version of Victory you are using. This can be done with the `flow-typed create-stub` command, e.g.:

```
flow-typed create-stub victory@^30.3.0
```

This will generate the files that declare the Flow types into the `./flow-typed` directory. This should remove any Flow errors you have related to Victory. You can learn more about declaring Flow types [in the Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/).

For third-party libraries in general, it's always best to see if the Flow types exist already, at which point you can install them. This can be done with the `flow-typed install` command, e.g.

```
flow-typed install bson@^1.0.0
```

For existing Flow types, you can also copy and paste declarations from [the existing definitions](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm) into your project's `./flow-typed` directory.